# JavaScript insert new line to any space in the middle of string

Tags: javascript, string

I would like to insert only 1 new line character roughly in the middle of a string:

```
for (var i=0; i<labels.length; i++){
      if (labels[i].length > 30) {
               //The split would occur here 
      }
}
```

Is there some JS function that does this?

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12427495/1117720

Comment: replace space with \n

Comment: What do you want to do after splitting?

Comment: Do you want a new line?  Or a `<br />`?  Very odd why you'd want to put presentation logic into code (these days).

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

<del>To replace spaces in a string with a new line:</del>

<del>`string.replace(/ /g, '\n');`</del>

<del>`/ /g` refers to a global replace of all spaces found.</del>

Say your string is as follows:

`var string = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';`

You need to find the length of the string, the middle point, and the nearest space from the middle:

```
var length = string.length;
var middle = Math.round(length / 2);
var spaceNearMiddle = string.indexOf(' ', middle);
var string1 = string.substring(0, spaceNearMiddle);
var string2 = string.substring(spaceNearMiddle + 1, length);
```

The result of string1 and string2 would be "The quick brown fox" and "jumps over the lazy dog".

Comment: Thanks. but i only want 1 new line inserted roughly in the middle

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
for (var i=0; i<labels.length; i++){
  if (labels[i].length > 30) {
      var index = labels[i].indexOf(' ', 30);
      var part1 = labels[i].substring(0,30);
      var part2 = labels[i].substring(30);
      if(index != -1){
          labels[i] = part1 + '\n' + part2;
      }

  }
}
```

Comment: They looks about write but its splitting words as well as in, "I have this string" it does "I have th\nis string"
How do i ensure it only inserts the \n at spaces?