# Get array of sentences from lengthy string, without each array[index] exceeding a max char length

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a service that needs to take an array of sentences, split from a lengthy, original string (say 10,000 characters in length).

The total string in each array "item" needs to be a combined list of complete sentences (ending in a period), but the total character count of that combined list can't exceed 300 characters. If a trailing sentence brings the total character count of an array item to 301, the list must truncate that whole sentence, and use it as the beginning sentence of the next item in the array... until the original string is finally broken apart. This of course means that it's ok if a an array item is short of the 300 character max.

I realize the magic of Regular Expressions can do some pretty special things, but am not sure if this is even possible. If it is... golden! If not, I'd even settle for a Javascript function that can return the same results.

My mind simply can't fathom the method to achieve this, and I'm grateful for any help on this matter. Thanks.

Comment: What if an individual sentence itself exceeds 300 chars in length?

Comment: A regex for a string of not more than 300 characters that ends with a `dot` would be simply `([\S\s]{1,299}(?=\.)\.)\s*` (Into capturing group 1).  The problem is that a dot can also appear within a sentence -- i.e. if there are abbreviations.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: `(?=\.)\.` => `\.`

Comment: I suggest: `\S[\s\S]{1,298}\.` to skip leading and trailing spaces. Or to be more robust: `\S[\s\S]{1,298}\.(?=\s|$)` (assuming your sentences always end with a single dot)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I should have seen that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I want to accept one of these Regex's as the answer. They're more in-tune with my original ask... and unless impossible would then go for a JS function. However, the addition of the \S in @Casimir's example doesn't work in my codepen here unless I add "?" after it: http://codepen.io/daleyjem/pen/ZYepgv?editors=101

Comment: @daleyjem: sorry for your codepen but this pattern works: https://eval.in/242746

Answer (score 2):

You can view this as a kind of partitioning problem, where you want to partition an array into the longest chunks that match some criteria. We'll try to write this in a way which is as "readable" as possible. We want to be able to write:

```
// "Partition array of sentences into sub-arrays with combined length < 300."
var sentenceSubArrays = partition(sentences, combinedLengthLessThan300);
```

This assumes that you have pre-segmented your text into a `sentences` array. It will return an array of arrays, which we turn into an array of combined sentences at the bottom.

We'll define `combinedLengthLessThan300` as

```
// "Is combined length of strings in array less than 300?"
function combinedLengthLessThan300(array) { return combinedLength(array) <= 300; }
```

where `combinedLength` is just

```
// "Compute combined length of array as sum of length of each element."
function combinedLength(array) { 
  return sum(array.map(function(elt) { return elt.length; }));
}
```

using a `sum` function defined as

```
function add(a, b)  { return a+b; }
function sum(array) { return array.reduce(add); }
```

If you prefer, you could also write `combinedLength` as

```
function combinedLength(array) { return array.join('').length; }
```

Now, the fun part is writing the partition routine itself.

```
// "Partition an array into sub-arrays which satisfy some criterion."
function partition(array, fn) {
  array = [array];                          // start off with big sub-array
  for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++) {    // for each sub-array
    while (array[i].length > 1 &&           // if sub-array has 2 or more elts
        !fn(array[i])) {                    // and criteria fails 
      if (!array[i+1]) array.push([]);      // create a new sub-array if necessary
      array[i+1].unshift(array[i].pop());   // move offending elt to next sub-array
    }
  }
  return array;
}
```

How does this work? As indicated in the comments, the basic approach is to start off with a single sub-array with all the original elements in it. Then, we loop over each sub-array, and see if it satisfies the criteria. If it doesn't, we move its last element to the front of the next sub-array (creating it if necessary). I do not claim this is blazingly fast. Its performance is probably O(n^2). This implementation prioritizes clarity and brevity over performance.

We can test `partition` by using a simple criteria, that the length of each sub-array may not be more than 2:

```
>> partition([1,2,3,4,5], function(array) { return array.length <= 2; })
<< [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]
```

Finally, to turn the `sentenceSubArrays` into an array of concatenated strings:

```
// "Create array of combined sentences by joining sentences in sub-arrays.
var combinedSentences = sentenceSubArrays.map(function(array) {
    return array.join('');
});
```

Hopefully the resulting code is readable, maintainable, and extendible, and provides us with little utilities, notably `partition`, that we can re-use in other contexts.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you, you want to merge sentences into groups smaller or equal to 300 characters? Assuming a single sentence never exceeded 300 characters (which may not be a good assumption), I think you could do something like this:

```
// I didn't know if you have a string of sentences or an array of sentences.
// string of sentences => array of sentences
function sentences(string) {
    return string.split(". ");
}

// array of sentences => array of paragraphs less than or equal to 300 characters
function paragraphs(sentences) {
    var paragraph = "";
    var paragraphs = [];
    sentences.forEach(function (sentence) {
        if (paragraph.length + sentence.length <= 300) {
            paragraph += sentence;
        } else {
            paragraphs.push(paragraph);
            paragraph = sentence;
        }
    });
    if (paragraphs[paragraphs.length - 1] !== paragraph) paragraphs.push(paragraph);
    return paragraphs;
}
```

Disclaimer: I didn't test this code.